# Scroll back to starting position in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I have scrolled a table horizontally. I want to scroll back to the starting position again. How can I achieve that?

Using this I have scrolled the table

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft += 400;", scrollElement);
```

Comment: `arguments[0].scrollRight += 400;` ?

Comment: no...i dont think there is anything called scrollRight in javascript

Comment: Then try with minus `arguments[0].scrollLeft -= 400;`

Comment: Good, I posted it as the answer, pls mark it as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go left with negative value:

```
arguments[0].scrollLeft -= 400;
```